# How do I make my JSON less verbose?

Tags: ajax, string, json, serialization

I'm currently developing a web application and using JSON for ajax requests and responses. I have an area where I return a very large dataset to the client in the form of an array of over  10000 objects. Here's part of the example (its been simplified somewhat):

```
"schedules": [
        {
            "codePractice": 35,
            "codeScheduleObject": 576,
            "codeScheduleObjectType": "",
            "defaultCodeScheduleObject": 12,
            "name": "Dr. 1"
        },
        {
            "codePractice": 35,
            "codeScheduleObject": 169,
            "codeScheduleObjectType": "",
            "defaultCodeScheduleObject": 43,
            "name": "Dr. 2"
        },
        {
            "codePractice": 35,
            "codeScheduleObject": 959,
            "codeScheduleObjectType": "",
            "defaultCodeScheduleObject": 76,
            "name": "Dr. 3"
        }
    ]
```

As, you can imagine, with a very large number of objects in this array, the size of the JSON reponse can be quite large.

My question is, is there a JSON stringifier/parser that would convert the `"schedules"` array to look something like this as a JSON string:

```
"schedules": [
    ["codePractice", "codeScheduleObject", "codeLogin", "codeScheduleObjectType", "defaultCodeScheduleObject","name"],
    [35, 576, "", 12, "Dr. 1"],
    [35, 169, "", 43, "Dr. 2"],
    [35, 959, "", 76, "Dr. 3"],
]
```

ie, that there would be an array at the beginning of the `"schedules"` array that held the keys of the objects this array, and all of the other container arrays would hold the values.

I could, if I wanted, do the conversion on the server and parse it on the client, but I'm wondering if there's a standard library for parsing/stringifying large JSON?

I could also run it through a minifier, but I'd like to keep the keys I have currently as they give some context within the application.

I'm also hoping you might critique my approach here or suggest alternatives?

Comment: Try to use gzip feature at your server or even try to gzip JSON response by PHP (and send it with special header of course).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using gzip.

Comment: I would keep the schema and the data separate (e.g. `{schema:, data:}`) -- but otherwise I think it's valid. I'm not sure of any existing library for this. However, after GZIP, will it result in mega-savings? I'm not sure but partially doubt it because of the *good duplication of key names* that exists. Mocking up a test-case (normal vs. normal + GZIP vs. hypothetical-schema vs. hypothetical-schema + GZIP) would be a good first step to check potential merits of this approach.

Comment: I've had to do similar with data structures to bring their size down. However, it's always a custom job. If you want to get all the advantage out of such an encoding technique, then you'll probably need to write custom rather than employ a library of sorts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HTTP compression (i.e. gzip or deflate) already does exactly that. Repeated patterns, like your JSON keys, are replaced with tokens so that the verbose pattern only has to occur once per transmission.

Comment: I have posted some simulated answers in my "not answer". A GZip of the original does offer the best *compression ratio*. However, the schema + GZip is the *smallest size*. Thus, GZip, being a general-purpose compression and not a specialized encoder, is *not able* to take full advantage of the duplication although it does a pretty darn good job. (The GZip of the original is smaller than just the schema version because it also compresses all the in-between-bits and the "bogus" name, etc.)

Comment: That's exactly right, thanks... Even though I have gzip enabled, I was hoping to get it down even more... Looks like I'll have to try to optimize my solution in another ways.

Comment: While you're considering other optimizations, keep in mind that your bottleneck may not be in transmission.  Even 10,000 records like those should compress down to less than 200k over the wire.  Whatever you're doing with them on the client-side, using relatively slow JavaScript, is likely to be much slower than the actual HTTP transmission time (and adding more complexity to how the message must be reconstituted or used in JavaScript will add to that client-side burden).

Comment: Why waste CPU time compressing when you can use a shorter format? I like OP's table-like format, and it's not difficult to implement.

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer, but to give a rough estimate of "savings" based on 10k entries and some bogus data :-) This is in response to a comment I posted. Will the added complexity make the schema'ized approach worth it?

"It depends."

This C# is [LINQPad](http://json.org) and is ready-to-go for testing/modifying:

```
string LongTemplate (int n1, int n2, int n3, string name) {
    return string.Format(@"
            {{
                ""codePractice"": {0},
                ""codeScheduleObject"": {1},
                ""codeScheduleObjectType"": """",
                ""defaultCodeScheduleObject"": {2},
                ""name"": ""Dr. {3}""
            }}," + "\n", n1, n2, n3, name);
}

string ShortTemplate (int n1, int n2, int n3, string name) {
    return string.Format("[{0}, {1}, \"\", {2}, \"Dr. {3}\"],\n",
        n1, n2, n3, name);
}

string MinTemplate (int n1, int n2, int n3, string name) {
    return string.Format("[{0},{1},\"\",{2},\"Dr. {3}\"],",
        n1, n2, n3, name);
}

long GZippedSize (string s) {
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var gzip = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(gzip)) {
        sw.Write(s);
    }
    return ms.Position;
}

void Main()
{
    var r = new Random();
    var l = new StringBuilder();
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    var m = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        var n1 = r.Next(10000);
        var n2 = r.Next(10000);
        var n3 = r.Next(10000);

        var name = "bogus" + r.Next(50);
        l.Append(LongTemplate(n1, n2, n3, name));
        s.Append(ShortTemplate(n1, n2, n3, name));
        m.Append(MinTemplate(n1, n2, n3, name));
    }

    var lc = GZippedSize(l.ToString());
    var sc = GZippedSize(s.ToString());
    var mc = GZippedSize(s.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Long:\tNormal={0}\tGZip={1}\tCompressed={2:P}", l.Length, lc, (float)lc / l.Length));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Short:\tNormal={0}\tGZip={1}\tCompressed={2:P}", s.Length, sc, (float)sc / s.Length));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Min:\tNormal={0}\tGZip={1}\tCompressed={2:P}", m.Length, mc, (float)mc / m.Length));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Short/Long\tRegular={0:P}\tGZip={1:P}",
        (float)s.Length / l.Length, (float)sc / lc));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Min/Long\tRegular={0:P}\tGZip={1:P}",
        (float)m.Length / l.Length, (float)mc / lc));
}
```

My results:

```
Long:  Normal=1754614  GZip=197053  Compressed=11.23 %
Short:  Normal=384614  GZip=128252  Compressed=33.35 %
Min:  Normal=334614  GZip=128252  Compressed=38.33 %
Short/Long  Regular=21.92 %  GZip=65.09 %
Min/Long  Regular=19.07 %  GZip=65.09 %
```

Conclusion:

- The single biggest savings is to use GZIP (better than just using schema'ize).
- GZIP + schema'ized will be the smallest overall.
- With GZIP there is *no point* to use a normal JavaScript minimizer (in this scenario).
- Use GZIP (e.g. DEFLATE); it performs very well on repetitive structured text (900% compression on normal!).

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 6):

Here's an article that does pretty much what you're looking to do:

http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=104

At first glance, it looks like your example would be compressed down to the following after the first step of the algorithm, which will actually do more work on it in subsequent steps):

```
{
    "templates": [ 
        ["codePractice", "codeScheduleObject", "codeScheduleObjectType", "defaultCodeScheduleObject", "name"] 
    ],
    "values": [ 
        { "type": 1, "values": [ 35, 576, "", 12, "Dr. 1" ] },
        { "type": 1, "values": [ 35, 169, "", 43, "Dr. 2" ] },
        { "type": 1, "values": [ 35, 959, "", 76, "Dr. 3" ] }
    ]
}
```

You can start to see the benefit of the algorithm already. Here's the final output after running it through the compressor:

```
{
    "f" : "cjson",
    "t" : [
              [0,"schedules"],
              [0,"codePractice","codeScheduleObject","codeScheduleObjectType","defaultCodeScheduleObject","name"]
          ],
    "v" : {
        "" : [ 1, [
                { "" : [2, 35, 576, "", 12, "Dr. 1"] },
                { "" : [2, 35, 169, "", 43, "Dr. 2"] },
                { "" : [2, 35, 959, "", 76, "Dr. 3"] }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

One can obviously see the improvement if you have several thousands of records. The output is still readable, but I think the other guys are right too: a good compression algorithm is going to remove the blocks of text that are repeated anyway...

Comment: It's "*readable*" but only after doing some head-parsing to work out the *intent*. +1 anyway, for information and link the schema'izing.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think that I was just underestimating exactly what Gzip could do for me.

Answer (score 3):

Before you change your JSON schema give this a shot

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 0):

For the record, i am doing exactly it in php. Its a list of objects from a database.

```
$comp=base64_encode(gzcompress(json_encode($json)));
```

json: string(22501 length)

gz compressed = string(711) but its a binary format.

gz compressed + base64 = string(948) its a text format.

So, its considerably smaller by using a fraction of second.